# Creating a density histogram in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, histogram, probability-density

I want to create the next histogram density plot with `ggplot2`. In the "normal" way (base packages) is really easy:

```
set.seed(46)
vector <- rnorm(500)  
breaks <- quantile(vector,seq(0,1,by=0.1))
labels = 1:(length(breaks)-1)
den = density(vector)
hist(df$vector,
     breaks=breaks,
     col=rainbow(length(breaks)),
     probability=TRUE)
lines(den)
```

[image]

With ggplot I have reached this so far:

```
seg <- cut(vector,breaks,
           labels=labels,
           include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE)
df = data.frame(vector=vector,seg=seg)

ggplot(df) + 
     geom_histogram(breaks=breaks,
                    aes(x=vector,
                        y=..density..,
                        fill=seg)) + 
     geom_density(aes(x=vector,
                      y=..density..))
```

But the "y" scale has the wrong dimension. I have noted that the next run gets the "y" scale right.

```
 ggplot(df) + 
     geom_histogram(breaks=breaks,
                    aes(x=vector,
                    y=..density..,
                    fill=seg)) + 
     geom_density(aes(x=vector,
                      y=..density..))
```

I just do not understand it. `y=..density..` is there, that should be the height. So why on earth my scale gets modified when I try to fill it?

I do need the colours. I just want a histogram where the breaks and the colours of each block are directionally set according to the default ggplot fill colours.

Comment: I edited your submission so that the code would fit on the page. You might be interested in Google's suggestions on how to code for maximum readability and utility: see http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Manually, I added colors to your percentile bars. See if this works for you.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=vector)) +   
   geom_histogram(breaks=breaks,aes(y=..density..),colour="black",fill=c("red","orange","yellow","lightgreen","green","darkgreen","blue","darkblue","purple","pink")) + 
   geom_density(aes(y=..density..)) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)) +
   ylab("Density") + xlab("df$vector") + ggtitle("Histogram of df$vector") +
   theme_bw() + theme(plot.title=element_text(size=20),
                      axis.title.y=element_text(size = 16, vjust=+0.2),
                      axis.title.x=element_text(size = 16, vjust=-0.2),
                      axis.text.y=element_text(size = 14),
                      axis.text.x=element_text(size = 14),
                      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I have been looking for alternative solutions but I have ended up with yours.

Answer (score 9):

`fill=seg` results in grouping. You are actually getting a different histogram for each value of `seg`. If you don't need the colours, you could use this:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=breaks,aes(x=vector,y=..density..), position="identity") + 
  geom_density(aes(x=vector,y=..density..))
```

[image]

If you need the colours, it might be easiest to calculate the density values outside of ggplot2.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the priviledge to post this as a comment but I think it just about qualifies as an answer to save others time who may hit this.  The `aes(y = ..density..)` syntax is now deprecated. See:

> Warning messages:
> 1: The dot-dot notation (`..density..`) was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
> ℹ Please use `after_stat(density)` instead.
> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.

So those `=..density..` in the everything above (which was helpful to me!) should now be `=after_stat(density)`

Comment: I agree, this does constitute a new answer given the deprecated notation. However, your answer would be improved if you include a full working example. That way, others will be able to more easily validate and  *use* your answer. Thanks

Comment: Ah, very fair. This absolutely minimal reprex shows the change (and produces a very ugly histogram!)  

`library(tidyverse)`  
`set.seed(2) # get replicability!`  
`df <- tibble(x = rnorm(50)) # generate data`  
`ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x)) +`  
    `   ### this next aes(y = after_stat(density)) replaces the now deprecated`   aes(y = ..density..)`  
   `    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)))`
Sorry for the format mess there.  I am trying to follow the instructions for formatting in in a comment but I am not winning.  I do find stackoverflow a rather hostile environment!

Comment: Nearly there :) I meant you need to add your code to a codeblock to your question rather than post your code as a comment. To create a codeblock in your question, first click "Edit". To start a codeblock, enter three backticks ```, and the same to close it. I'll update your question to show you how for future reference. My edits may not show immediately though as I don't have enough rep yet. Hope this helps.

Comment: And FYI, your code throws the warning: `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`. You could update your code to something like `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), bins = 40)` so inexperienced users don't get confused. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: I was doing the three backticks, simply wasn't working. Tried each line separately, tried the four space indentation.  Nothing seemed to behave.  (Sounds like we're both stuck with the reputation issue.)  As to the warning, I did assume that everyone, even a newbie, running `geom_histogram()` would have seen that as I think I've yet to call `geom_histogram()` and *not* see it!  However, I take your point.  If you can reformat things do please add a bin count or bindwidth to preempt the message/warning.  Thanks!

Comment: Done. You don't need rep to edit your own answer IIRC. And yes, I too found creating codeblocks challenging at first. If you click "Edit" you will be able to see how it's done for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion regarding interpreting the `y-axis` might be due to density is plotted rather than count. So, the values on the `y-axis` are proportions of the total sample, where the *sum of the bars is equal to `1`*.

Answer (score 1):

Or an option with `ggpubr`

```
library(ggpubr)
gghistogram(df, x = "vector", add = "mean", rug = TRUE, fill = "seg",
   palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#E5A800", "#00BFAB", "#01ADFA", 
   "#00FABA", "#00BEAF", "#01AEBF", "#00EABA", "#00EABB"), add_density = TRUE)
```