# How could I insert a histogram into a `geom_smooth` plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to mimic some figures from journal papers. Here is an example from `Schlenker and Roberts (2009)`.

[image]

I'd like to add a similar histogram to my own plot. Please see below. Is it possible to achieve this task with `ggplot`? Thanks.
[image]

See a `dput` data below. `rh` represents `x` axis and `yhat1` indicates the `y` axis.

```
> dput(df.m[,c('rh','yhat1')])
structure(list(rh = c(11L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 
86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 
99L, 100L), yhat1 = c(0.0097784, 0.111762325, 0.0887123966666667, 
0.24714677, 0.079887235, 0.162714825, 0.24789043, 0.107558165, 
0.182885584545455, 0.136690964444444, 0.159203683333333, 0.5156053805, 
0.587034213636364, 0.233377613, 0.31531245, 0.4778449572, 0.212574774137931, 
0.2274105676, 0.253733041707317, 0.560999839354839, 0.224892959444444, 
0.392268151304348, 0.351498776603774, 0.366547010727273, 0.35013903469697, 
0.382026272372881, 0.510611202461538, 0.391176294871795, 0.423356474328358, 
0.380316089137931, 0.459821489651163, 0.388949226593407, 0.506833284166667, 
0.459263999259259, 0.558535709906542, 0.745323656071429, 0.60167464606383, 
0.72210854266129, 0.695203745656566, 0.638265557105263, 0.52373110503876, 
0.611695133046875, 0.963833986386555, 0.803060819275362, 0.837984669112426, 
0.7931166204, 0.870764136976744, 1.21005393820225, 0.862845527777778, 
1.028402381125, 1.2077895633526, 1.01176334204082, 1.08139833964706, 
0.90346288, 1.05871937863014, 1.27788244930233, 1.16250975336634, 
1.1450916525, 1.4412301412, 1.21264826238281, 1.35417930411504, 
1.18588206727273, 1.40277204710084, 1.33194569259259, 1.18413544210084, 
1.22718163528571, 1.33992107226667, 1.44770425268156, 1.43974964777778, 
1.26656031551351, 1.58998655363636, 1.29994566024272, 1.46398530493902, 
1.26061274530055, 1.30718501225275, 1.20523443567901, 1.23789593428571, 
1.34433582230769, 1.36438752851852, 1.5915544857037, 1.10979387898438, 
1.31898147708661, 1.426120105, 1.52075980155738, 1.40629729460177, 
0.9048366681, 1.2973945580531, 1.37696154192982)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -88L))
```

Comment: Like so? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061653/creating-a-density-histogram-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this can get you started:

```
library(ggplot2)
breaks <- 20
maxcount <- max(table(cut(df.m$rh,breaks = 20))) + 1
ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x = rh)) + 
  stat_smooth(formula = y ~ x, aes(y = yhat1 * 10 + maxcount), method = "loess") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,5), "Exposure (Days)",
                       sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - maxcount) /10,
                                           "Log of Daily Confirmed Case Counts")) +
  geom_histogram(bins = breaks, color = "black", fill = "green") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 85, xend = 85, y = 0 + maxcount, yend = Inf),
               col = "red", linetype = "dashed") + 
  labs(x = "Relative Humidity Percentage") + theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.line.y.left = element_line(color= "green"), 
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(hjust = 0.05, color = "green"))
```

[image]